# Why will my web app not send data to my google firebase database?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

My web app using ember.js will not send data to the google firebase realtime database

I have viewed multiple tutorials and searched the web and cannot seem to find the answer to my problem. I am using ember v 3.10

```
actions: {

  saveInvitation() {
    const email = this.get.emailAddress;

    const newInvitation = this.store.createRecord('invitation', { email });

    newInvitation.save().then(response => {
      this.set('responseMessage', `Thank you! id: ${response.get('id')}`);
      this.set('emailAddress', '');
    });

  },

}
```

My Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

  email: DS.attr('string'),

});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no errors, but in the ember inspector it shows a rejected state from the "then" promise; "Error: Cannot read property 'initializedRelationships' of undefined"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Not sure why you're getting close votes, your questions  seem ok to me...  Is your snippet above in a controller or a route?  Also, `this.get.emailAddress` doesn't look, right-  it would normally be `this.get('emailAddress')`

Answer (score 2):

It seems in my newness, I had overlooked what version of emberfire I was using/needed.  When emberfire installed, it defaulted to the LTS of 2.x but I need 3.x using ember 3.10.

also, yes I needed to change my code to `this.get('emailAddress').`